# Problems with dynamic memory allocation for structs in C

Tags: c, struct, malloc, realloc, wchar-t

I'm given an unknown amount of "wide symbols". The text is formatted as sentences, which i have to add to struct "Text".

These are my structs:

```
struct Sentence {
    wchar_t *sentence;
    int amount_of_symbols;
};

struct Text {
    struct Sentence *sentences;
    int amount_of_sentences;
};
```

I dynamically allocate memory for array of "Sentence" structs and add them. 
This is my input code:

```
int amount_of_sentences = 0;
struct Sentence *sentences = (struct Sentence *) malloc(amount_of_sentences * sizeof(struct Sentence));

struct Text text = {sentences, amount_of_sentences};

wchar_t symbol;
int buffer_size = 0;
wchar_t *buffer = (wchar_t *) malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(wchar_t));

bool sentence_begun = true;

while (true) {
    symbol = getwchar();

    if (symbol == '\n')
        break;

    if (sentence_begun && symbol == ' ') {
        sentence_begun = false;
        continue;
    }

    buffer = (wchar_t *) realloc(buffer, (++buffer_size) * sizeof(wchar_t));
    buffer[buffer_size - 1] = symbol;

    if (symbol == '.') {
        buffer[buffer_size] = '\0';

        text.amount_of_sentences++;
        text.sentences = (struct Sentence *) realloc(text.sentences, text.amount_of_sentences * sizeof(struct Sentence));
        text.sentences[text.amount_of_sentences - 1].amount_of_symbols = buffer_size;
        text.sentences[text.amount_of_sentences - 1].sentence = (wchar_t *) malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(wchar_t));
        text.sentences[text.amount_of_sentences - 1].sentence = buffer;

        buffer_size = 0;
        buffer = (wchar_t *) realloc(buffer, buffer_size * sizeof(wchar_t));
        sentence_begun = true;
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be fine, but as soon as i try to output all my sentences, not all of them are shown and some of the are repeated.

This is my output code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.amount_of_sentences; i++) {
    wprintf(L"%ls\n", text.sentences[i].sentence);
}
```

Example of input-output:

```
adjsand. asdad.a.a. aaaa. adsa.


a.

adsa.
adsa.
```

What can be wrong with this code and what should i change?

Comment: Could you show how `text` and `sentence_begun` are declared and initialized?

Comment: @Schwern, 
    int amount_of_sentences = 0;
    struct Sentence *sentences = (struct Sentence *) malloc(amount_of_sentences * sizeof(struct Sentence));
    struct Text text = {sentences, amount_of_sentences};
    bool sentence_begun = true;

Comment: [Please edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53741132/edit) with that so the code example is more complete.

Comment: @Schwern, done with changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here.

```
    text.sentences[text.amount_of_sentences - 1].sentence = (wchar_t *) malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(wchar_t));
    text.sentences[text.amount_of_sentences - 1].sentence = buffer;

    buffer_size = 0;
    buffer = (wchar_t *) realloc(buffer, buffer_size * sizeof(wchar_t));
```

You allocate a fresh sentence with `malloc` and then overwrite it with `buffer`. This will leak memory.

Then you assign `buffer` to `text.sentences[text.amount_of_sentences - 1].sentence` and then free that memory by reallocating `buffer`.

From the C standard...

> ***The realloc function deallocates the old object pointed to by ptr*** and returns a pointer to a new object that has the size specified by size.

`text.sentences[text.amount_of_sentences - 1].sentence` winds up pointing to freed memory. This will lead to undefined behavior.

Instead, point to `buffer` and allocate a new `buffer`.

```
    text.sentences[text.amount_of_sentences - 1].sentence = buffer;

    buffer_size = 0;
    buffer = malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(wchar_t));
```

---

Some other notes...

[As Paul noted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3100312/paul-ogilvie), you need to allocate an extra byte for the null byte.

[There's no need to cast the result of `malloc` or `realloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

It's simpler, faster, and less bug prone to allocate a large buffer on the stack to read input into (growing it if necessary). Then copy the contents to appropriately sized memory.

[I went ahead and coded up an improved version](https://gist.github.com/schwern/75f4bf42baf36042a5416cf782438438) to illustrate. If this is homework, please don't hand this in.

Comment: It helped. Thank you, Schwern and Paul Ogilvie!

Comment: @НикитаБабенко You're welcome. I went ahead and coded up a version with the improvements I was talking about. https://gist.github.com/schwern/75f4bf42baf36042a5416cf782438438 Use it for illustration, but if this is homework please don't turn it in as your own work.

Answer (score 0):

First, your buffer is 1 too small and doesn't account for the terminating `'\0'`. At the top of your program, do:

```
int buffer_size = 1;
wchar_t *buffer = (wchar_t *) malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(wchar_t));
*buffer= '\0';
```

But the real problem is in:

```
    text.sentences[text.amount_of_sentences - 1].sentence =
                (wchar_t *) malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(wchar_t));
    text.sentences[text.amount_of_sentences - 1].sentence = buffer;

    buffer_size = 0;
    buffer = (wchar_t *) realloc(buffer, buffer_size * sizeof(wchar_t));
```

You allocate memory for the sentence, but then you overwrite that pointer with the `buffer` pointer. Next you reset the buffer size and reallocate the buffer.

The assignment does *not* copy the buffer data. To do that, do:

```
    strcpy(text.sentences[text.amount_of_sentences - 1].sentence, buffer);
```

and here too, do:

```
buffer_size = 1;
buffer = (wchar_t *) realloc(buffer, buffer_size * sizeof(wchar_t));
*buffer= '\0';
```

Comment: It didn't help. The output is similar to the first one.

Comment: I forgot... `buffer[buffer_size] = '\0';` should be `buffer[buffer_size-1] = '\0';` If that doesn't fix it (and I can't find anytrhing more wrong with the code), you must take the program in a debugger and step through it, checking at each step if it still OK.

Comment: Also: `amount_of_symbols = buffer_size -1;` because the last char is the `'\0'`

Comment: And: `buffer[buffer_size - 2] = symbol;` for the same reason.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Is `strcpy` safe with `wchar_t *`?